# iptables rule for local network with free internet blocking unrequested connection from internet to server?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, internet

I have a home server (with slackware 13) with a eth0 for the local network and a eth1 for the internet (cable modem with dynamic ip).

While I do want to learn more about iptables I am still on the proccess and I need some rules done and can't until a learn to do it as I dont wish my server to get compromised at this stage.

I currently have a vm where I play with my rules and everything and would appreciate if some one could wrap me a firewall rule for iptables to do the below:

1. Allow all users from my dhcp server
   on eth0 to have full access to
   internet and server, in other words
   eth0 should have no restrictions
   within the network and server.
2. Allow all users to be able to create
   a server, for example if they are
   playing a game such as for example
   warcraft, and they create a game,
   the firewall should allow the
   negotiation of those connections to
   go thru.
3. Block any requests from internet to
   server unless it was initiated by
   the server or an users from the
   network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, basically your Linux box acts as a firewall?

First, enable IP forwarding.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
```

Then, add some forwarding rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Secure the FORWARD chain:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Create a NAT rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Finally, don't forget to check that you have a default route:

```
ip route show | grep default
```

You should see something like:

```
default via <IP_of_eth1's_gateway> dev eth1
```

If not, add one:

```
ip route add default vie <IP_of_eth1's_gateway> dev eth1
```

(Usually the DHCP client will automatically add one)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had already done the masquerade, and forwarding steps, and dhcpcd had alreay added the route as you said so now I am testing the forward on eth0, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For allowing servers, you can manually add port-forward rules, or use a uPnP daemon (if the applications support uPnP - many do...) `[linux-igd][1]` should do that...

NAT-PMP is similar and used by some other applications. An implementation for Linux is [here](http://tedp.id.au/stallone/).